# How to show time format from 00:00 to 24:00 for day view/week view at Jquery FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

In `Jquery` Full Calendar getting some issues showing time format at day view and week view.

I am unable to show time format 00:00 to 24:00 in day view and week view, all the time getting 00:00 to 23:00 whereas it is actually 00:00 to 24:00 .

I used code below to show time format (00:00 - 24:00):

```
(
    allDaySlot: true,
    allDayText: 'Volledige dag',
    firstHour: 8,
    slotMinutes: 30,
    defaultEventMinutes: 120,
    axisFormat: 'HH:mm',
    timeFormat: {
        agenda: 'H:mm{ - h:mm}'
    },
    dragOpacity: {
        agenda: .5
    },
    minTime: 0,
    maxTime: 24
)
```

Please help me if any one have any solution.

Thanks,
Rama

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is very old. But if someone find this question, you can easily show that range with :

```
        minTime: "00:00:00",
        maxTime: "23:59:59"
```

Answer (score -1):

I would say that this is because you cannot get 24:00, it would be 00:00 (midnight) as 24:00 is not correct. 24 hour clocks only go from 00:00 to 23:00.

There is a previous Stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563870/chrome-not-recognizing-240000-while-firefox-does) and a link from within that question [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), which explains that 24:00 can be used to notify the end of a day, while 00:00 is used for the beginning but both are correct.

Comment: Thanks James, 
It's fine...As we know 24 hours clock only go from 00:00 to 23:00 but is it possible to show time-frame in calendar from 00:00 to 00:00 in a day view. I mean to say in day view like below
00:00
01:00
02:00 
.....
.....
.
.
.
.
.....
.....
23:00
00:00