# CoreData's `Date` type transforms `0000-01-01T00:00:00Z` to `nil`

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

I'm new to iOS and CoreData, so I'm sorry if this is too basic.

I'm trying to figure out why a valid-but-odd date of `0000-01-01T00:00:00Z` is being transformed to `nil`. eg:

```
calculatedAttrMapping.valueTransformer(@"0000-01-01T00:00:00Z"); // nil
```

This date should work, I think. It's valid by the RFC and ISO specs.

```
new Date("0000-01-01T00:00:00Z"); //Sat Jan 01 0 07:00:00 GMT+0700 (ICT)
```

(not that JS is relevant, but as a gut check...)

I tried stepping into it in the debugger, but it goes to assembly before I see anything useful.

Is this coming from the configuration in the `.xcdatamodeld` GUI?
Is this intentional behavior? A limitation?

Comment: Related date test cases: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005374/ecmascript-5-date-parse-results-for-iso-8601-test-cases

Comment: As far as i'm aware, ISO format dates are not compatable with `NSDate` and `NSDateFormatter`. I actually ended up writing my own ISO date parser, (i.e. NSDate to ISO and ISO string to NSDate). I would either save the date as a string, or if you need to use it as an NSDate write a parser. I'm assuming your using Swift? What does `println(Date("0000-01-01T00:00:00Z")) print? (I dont have Xcode to hand sorry).

Comment: What is `calculatedAttrMapping`?

Comment: @TomHarrington it's pulled by iterating the `attributes` of an instance of a CoreData Managed Object's Entity Class. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15861892/core-data-not-automatically-calling-value-transformer-when-getting-setting-att

Comment: @SimplGy None of Core Data's classes have a `valueTransformer` method or property. That's why I asked, because it's not apparent what your sample line of code is trying to do.

Comment: @TomHarrington isn't this it? It has a `valueTransformerName`: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSAttributeDescription_Class/index.html I'm new to iOS and reading code that is deep and abstracted so I'm not clear on what's going on either.

Comment: If the method name isn't the same then it's not the same method. Also, `valueTransformerName` doesn't take any arguments, so it wouldn't make sense to call it as your snippet shows.

Comment: @TomHarrington fair enough. I'm not sure which parts are CoreData, which parts are mogenerator, and which parts are custom. Still figuring it out. Let me see if I can ask a better question after looking at it some more. It is telling that the default date parser fails  on the `0000` date, I think that's my ultimate answer, but it's not the "why".

Answer (score 0):

```
let dateStringFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateStringFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
var d = dateStringFormatter.dateFromString("0001-01-01T00:00:00Z")
```

Returns `Some "Jan 1, 1, 6:42 AM"`

```
let dateStringFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateStringFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
var d = dateStringFormatter.dateFromString("0000-01-01T00:00:00Z")
```

Returns `nil`

This shows that for Swift using NSDateFormatter, it can't parse a `0000` year.

There are two big assumptions here if I'm going to say this applies to the CoreData case.

1. Swift and Objective C Parse dates using the same code path
2. Objective C uses a date string formatter when parsing dates for core data attributes of type Date

Comment: from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24089999/how-do-you-create-a-swift-date-object